# How can I add a keyboard shortcut to a plank shortcut?

Tags: release-loki, plank, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to open the first application shortcut of plank with "windows button + 1" exactly like Windows 10.

Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

Comment: I don't think plank has this feature. there are docks that have a similar feature. You could replace plank with a different dock.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/749899/a-dock-for-ubuntu-that-has-keyboard-shortcuts-for-open-programs

Comment: This thread is about the same question: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/1z5pi1/keyboard_shortcut_to_open_plank_apps_with_a_twist/